# Custom Fields for Author Box

Tags: posts

have a question about best practice for adding fields to author form. The site will post blogs on behalf of another author, but wants an author box at the bottom that would include the "real" authors picture, name, business name, and links to social media. A typical author box won't work since it ties to the author publishing the post.

What would be best practice with this? I really only dabble with HTML and CSS so styling it won't be a problem, but not sure if custom fields will work here, or if there is a better practice for this. Love the site and all the help everyone offers. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add they have custom fields but it doesn't seem like this will display like it should. Has anyone used this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Have either of the answers resolved your issue yet? Please mark as correct if so, or don't be afraid to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new custom field to the author profile

```
function my_epl_custom_user_contact( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['custom']   = __( 'Custom', 'easy-property-listings' );    
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter ('user_contactmethods','my_epl_custom_user_contact',10,1);
```

Create the HTML output of the Custom Fields

```
function my_epl_get_custom_author_html($html = '') {
    global $epl_author;    
    if ( $epl_author->custom != '' ) {
        $html = '
            <a class="epl-author-icon author-icon custom-icon-24" href="http://custom.com/' . $epl_author->custom . '"
                title="'.__('Follow', 'easy-property-listings' ).' ' . $epl_author->name . ' '.__('on Custom', 'easy-property-listings' ).'">'.
                 __('C', 'easy-property-listings' ).
            '</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Add the custom field filter

```
function my_epl_custom_social_icons_filter( $html ) { 
    $html .= my_epl_get_custom_author_html();
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'epl_author_email_html' , 'my_epl_custom_social_icons_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in custom fields for most of this, but Advanced Custom Fields will be especially useful for making the author image part easy and is worth using for sure. You can go to Dashboard >> Custom Fields after activating the plugin, and easily create a new Field Group Called "Custom Author" or whatever suits you, and it should automatically be attached to the posts post type. After that you can add a text field for a custom author name, and an image field for a custom author image, and fields for whatever else you may need to display.

Once you have your advanced custom fields created(not going to delve into that too much here), a user can fill in your advanced custom author fields on any post, and you can output those fields in your themes template files(likely single.php for when a single post is being viewed). The output/display part is entirely up to you, but I'll show one way you could display a custom text field called "custom_author_name" and a custom image field called "custom_author_image":

```
<section class="post-meta">

    <span class='post-author-name'>
    <?php
        $customAuthor = sanitize_text_field( get_field('custom_author_name') ); // Store safe/sanitized value of custom field in variable
        if($customAuthor) { // If custom_author_name field is set, display it
            echo $customAuthor;
        } else { // Otherwise fallback to display the normal post author name
            echo get_the_author();
        }
    ?>
    </span>

    <?php
        $customAuthorImage = get_field('custom_author_image');
        if($customAuthorImage) { // If custom_author_image field is set...

            // ... Then put effort into storing sanitized data we need
            $url = esc_url( $customAuthorImage['url'] );
            $alt = esc_attr( $customAuthorImage['alt'] );
            $title = esc_attr( $customAuthorImage['title'] );

            // ... And finally display our custom image field in an img tag
            echo '<img class="custom-author-image" src="' . $url . '" alt="' . $alt . '" title="' . $title . '">';
        } 
    ?>

</section>
```

As far as best practices, use strong logic in your php(you might add stronger conditional logic to how I check if the custom fields are set, and maybe only display the image if the authors name is set for example), and also be sure you sanitize or escape all data when outputting it on the front end.

Also, I'm happy to offer more help if you get stuck on this, just add a comment here.